# Simple TSQL table referencing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp

I am trying to use a variable table to steer a mirrored report sproc so that I can push out a single kind of report relating to this IS number:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[report
(@Date DATETIME='11/11/2011')
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT *
   INTO #Temp
   FROM dbo.vwview
   WHERE
        Date = @Date

   DECLARE @tblnewReport TABLE(IS varchar(8))

   SELECT subreportIS
   INTO @tblnewReport
   FROM #Temp
```

Basically, my `@tblnewReport` being where it is is the problem. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: change as insert INTO @tblnewReport  SELECT subreportIS from #Temp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[report
(
 @Date DATETIME='11/11/2011'
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM  dbo.vwview
WHERE
        Date = @Date
DECLARE @tblnewReport TABLE
(IS varchar(8))

INSERT
INTO @tblnewReport
SELECT SubreportIS FROM #Temp
```

Comment: Oh my god.  Okay, I totally see my error.  I really appreciate this and it works.  It won't let me +1 you yet because I don't have the rep yet (because I'm a little reputation baby so far), but it works and you're awesome!

EDIT: I lied, it just needed to refresh.  You're my hero.